# Woocommerce API returning JSON with Content-Type: text/html

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to connect my Woocommerce installation to an external service (Trustpilot) that requires the `Content-Type` set to `application/json`, but when I use the API, the header returns `Content-Type: text/html`.

I found [this post on their GitHub](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8086) from 2015, but it doesn't seem fixed.

Is there any way I can force the API to return `Content-Type: application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it was an issue with the plugin WP Super Cache

Comment: Can you please explain how you fixed it?